# input textbox display end string than from start

Tags: javascript, html, input, styles

When we have a string = "aaaaabbb" inside the textbox width of 5 letters.
Instead of [aaaaa], I want to see [aabbb] on rest.

I've tried:

1)    direction: rtl <- this seemed to be working for displaying However, when I tried to write more after abcdefghijklmn(more words), words write from beginning of the text. (ex. opqrstu[abcdefghijklmn]) which I do not want.

2)    text-align: right <- this will only pull the text to right side of the textbox. Will not show end letters.

```
<input class="control" style=" width:18%; height:100%; margin-right: .5%;" id="link${customer.customerId}" value=${customer.link}></input>
```

When I have long~~~ link address, I want to see the last part before me having to click to see because first part is all same string with https://....etc

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU you cannot.

direction: rtl is for arab countries and other languages that write from right to left so all becames inverted.

This is a base functionality that is hard coded in the browser implementation of the component. The only way to change this is drawing the component from the scratch and providing all events for it. 
That is a very lengthy job for such a small thing.

Your only hope is maybe finding a component that is already developed that  provides this, a mask component or something. I don't know any that works this way.

**Edit**

Jquery-Mask-Plugin provides the "reverse" option. See if it fits your needs. Check "CPF" type.

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using template strings inside HTML attributes.  They typically only work when run inside script files.